# Remove Facebook Page update notifications from bar

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, notifications

I am the admin of a Facebook Page.  I am trying to remove the notifications I get every time someone likes the Page.

I am **not** trying to change the email notifications.  I do not receive any email notifications.

I am only trying to remove them from the top [image: What I'm talking about]

Can anyone help?

Comment: I, unfortunately, solved this situation in one case by de-admining myself from a page. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to currently remove this, at best as you said, all you can do is remove the email notifications.